# PDO query not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below is abit of my database class. the check function doesn't execute. I have var dump everything and it looks right but when i call the results method. I get no data from it. Please help

```
Class Database
    {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
    $_error = false, //store errors to see if the query as fail or not
    $_query, //last query executed
    $_results, // store result set
    $_count = 0, //count how many results
    $_lastinsertID; // last insert ID

    // method to insert database
    // constructor
    private function __construct()
        {
        try
            {
                //connect to database
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') , Config::get('mysql/username') , Config::get('mysql/password'));
            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo 'We\'re sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database';
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() , FILE_APPEND); // write some details to the PDOError file
            }
        }

    public function check($sql, $params = array()) {

        if(count($params)) {
            $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);

            foreach ($params as $param => $value) { 
                $this->_query->bindParam($param + 1, $value); 

            }

            if($this->_query->execute($params)) {

                //get the results
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll();

                //store the number of rows
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();


               return $this;
            }

    }

        return false;
}

//get results from query
    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

//return count the result set
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }

}
```

this is how the check method will intended to run

```
$check= Database::getInstance()->check('SELECT email, hash FROM users WHERE email = ? AND hash = ? AND status = ?', array('myemail@something.com', '1f3870be27derfc49b3e31a0c6728957f', 0));
```

when i `var_dump($check)` i get bool true

but when I do this

```
if($check->count()) {
    echo 'hello i am counting';
} else {
   echo 'sorry nothing';
}
```

when i run that if statement i get "sorry nothing". Which suggest thats the query has not execute. So when I do

```
if($check->results()) {
  echo "we have a result";
}
```

I do not get anything. That query above should return 1 result but it doesn't in this case. Please help.

Comment: [`rowCount`](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowcount) will return `0` for SELECT queries, unless e.g. `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` was used specifically.

Comment: @mario depends on database driver? With MySQL I haven't to specify that to get row counts. Or well if I do, I haven't noticed I've been doing it yet...

Comment: Is it just me or do you have an error in your query syntax? You forgot to close the quote of the 1st prepared array element.

Comment: @techouse i can't see where you are referring to

Comment: @Baako `array('myemail@something.com, '1f387` There, just after `.com`

Comment: @techouse thanks but that was not the issue

Comment: yep, what @ʰᵈˑ said ^

Comment: Hmm, since you're using `?` as placeholders you might wanna drop the `foreach` loop that binds the params since it's already done by PDO automatically in the `execute` method. And you could put an `else` in the `execute` condition where you would dump the PDO `errorInfo()` to help you out. Check this do see what I mean http://fpaste.org/149951/15782227/

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ that was not the issue

Comment: @techouse thank you very much please put that as an answer so I can tick it off as answered

Comment: if `$check` is a `boolean`, you can't call methods on it; `$check->count()` is invalid, `boolean`s don't have a method `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, since you're using ? as placeholders you might wanna drop the foreach loop that binds the params since it's already done by PDO automatically in the execute method. And you could put an else in the execute condition where you would dump the PDO errorInfo() to help you out.

```
class Database {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
    $_error = false, //store errors to see if the query as fail or not
    $_query, //last query executed
    $_results, // store result set
    $_count = 0, //count how many results
    $_lastinsertID; // last insert ID

    // method to insert database
    // constructor
    private function __construct() {
        try {
            //connect to database
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') , Config::get('mysql/username') , Config::get('mysql/password'));
        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'We\'re sorry but there was an error while trying to connect to the database';
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() , FILE_APPEND); // write some details to the PDOError file
        }
    }

    public function check($sql, $params = array()) {
        if(count($params)) {
            $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);

            ## drop this
            //foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
            //    $this->_query->bindParam($param + 1, $value);
            //}

            if($this->_query->execute($params)) {
                //get the results
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll();

                //store the number of rows
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

                return $this;
            }
            // add this to aid you
            else {
                throw new Exception($this->_query->errorInfo());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //get results from query
    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    //return count the result set
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```